# When a button is clicked change css without JavaScript?

Tags: css

When a button is clicked change css without JavaScript?

I believe you can do it by making a button a checkbox instead?

Thank you

Comment: change css of what?

Comment: of another div.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the "[checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)". You can use a `checkbox` or `radio`, then use the `:checked` pseudo class in CSS to target other elements on the page using the `+` or `~` sibling selectors. Here's an example.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  color: #09c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked ~ div {
  color: green;
}

input:checked + div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">click</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">

<div>adjacent element</div>

<div>general sibling</div>
<div>general sibling</div>
<div>general sibling</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way doing it with a button and not a checkbox hack?

Comment: @Kirnc not with just CSS. You either need to use the `input` or a `label` to toggle the `input` state of `:checked` or not. A button won't do that.